# What is wrong in my if and else statemenht?

Tags: java, if-statement

I did the test run of my exercise and the "The player is already in the team" will occur 3 times for what ever string input for variable newplayers if option equals y.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner; 

public  class Players {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> players = new ArrayList<>();
        players.add("Torres");
        players.add("Ronaldo");
        players.add("Rooney");
        System.out.println("This is the current items in the players \n" + players);

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Do you want to buy more players ????  y/n");
        String option = sc.nextLine();

        if (option.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {

            System.out.println("Please enter your favorite player  ");
            String newplayer = sc.nextLine();
            for (int i = 0; i < players.size(); i++) {
                if (newplayer.equalsIgnoreCase(players.get(i))) {
                    System.out.println("The player is already in the team   ");
                } else {
                    players.add(newplayer);
                }
            }

            System.out.println("New and old players are  " + players);
        } else {
            System.out.println("The current players we have are " + players);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Oh the problem is... Sec let me post a solution... It has to do with your loop

Comment: Hint: What happens when each checked person is not equal to new player?  Hint2: so when should we make decision of adding to players (is inside of loop proper place)?

Comment: Exactly... It adds the person when it is not equal player.. even if the index is still 0

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the for loop around your if which is as below:

```
for (int i = 0; i <players.size() ; i++) {//its because of this loop that if your input is in players list it loops three times and prints "...already in team"
    if (newplayer.equalsIgnoreCase(players.get(i))){
        System.out.println("The player is already in the team   ");
    } else {
        players.add(newplayer);
    }
}
```

Here you are running a loop which will go three times (as you have three players in your list). You shouldn't continue the loop once you find that player is already in team by using break in your method like below:

```
for (int i = 0; i <players.size() ; i++) {
   if (newplayer.equalsIgnoreCase(players.get(i))){
        System.out.println("The player is already in the team   ");
        break;
    } else {
        players.add(newplayer);
    }
}
```

Or even better, you store all your players in lower case and then use `contains` method on your player list like:

```
if (players.contains(newplayer.toLowerCase())) {
     //player exist
} else {
     // add player
}
```

Comment: he needs that for loop

Comment: I think he wants to run through the whole team and see if the person exists.... then add the player if it doesnt exist

Comment: So it seems, @DarkV1.

Comment: @Bo_lin I added some pseudo code/ code to my solution . it should work. Goodluck

Comment: Yes, I want to check if the the new player matches existing player, if no then it can be added in to the arraylist.

Comment: @Bo_Lin Did you tried above code? does above code fixes your issue?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the else part of your statement (20 runs through conditionals.)

```
 else {
    players.add(newplayer);
    }
```

That else is called every index that does not satisfy the if.
It is only needed to be called once the loop has interated through and the player is found to not have a team.

Logic/Pseudo Code: Therefore, the else statement should be fired once the index i is finished its last run to where it does not satisfy the loop. Therefore, if the loop has been iterated through, and a break statement wasn't reached.. That means the player does not have a team.. Then add the player.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < players.size(); i++) {
            if (newplayer.equalsIgnoreCase(players.get(i))) {
                System.out.println("The player is already in the team   ");
             break;
            }
            if(i = players.size()-1&& !newplayer.equalsIgnoreCase(players.get(i))
            {
                 //If the loop is iterated through and does not satisfy the first conditional, then that means it will reach this conditional without breaking. Which also means that the player does not have a team

                    players.add(newplayer);
            }
        }
```

Comment: it would work, but it would be inefficient: say you have 10 players and the new player you are trying to add is not already in the list. You will end up performing 20 tests just to add the new player. Not to mention that you are performing the test on the name twice

Comment: yes I mean the 2 if statements: they are not mutually exclusive so they will be checked at each iteration

Comment: I don't think an else statement would be helpful, but testing  a boolean outside the for loop would do the trick and add only one additional check so for 10 players you would perform 11 tests

Comment: indeed. It's just a matter of efficiency: your solution would work just fine

Answer (score 0):

Extracting the logic of *adding a player* from the `for loop` that *checks if the player is already there* will get the job done. 
It would also allow you to reuse the functionality of searching for a player by incapsulating the logic within a separate method and it would be more efficient as it would allow you to avoid unnecessary `if` checks.

Try this.

```
String newplayer = sc.nextLine();
boolean playerExists = false;
for (int i = 0; i < players.size(); i++) {
    if (newplayer.equalsIgnoreCase(players.get(i))) {
        playerExists = true;
        break;
    }
}
if(playerExists){
    System.out.println("The player is already in the team   ");
} else {
    players.add(newplayer);
}
```

Or with a separate method approach

```
if(playerExists()){
    System.out.println("The player is already in the team   ");
} else {
    players.add(newplayer);
}

// change access modifier and parameters according to your specific scenario...
private boolean playerExists(String player){
    for (int i = 0; i < players.size(); i++) {
        if (player.equalsIgnoreCase(players.get(i))) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: The output is the same.. you just delegated responsibility of the loop to a method.

Comment: @DarkV1 yes the output will be the same, but it'd be more efficient. I added a comment to your answer